# How to efficiently lookup linked cells in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist

Input: a list of cells. Each cell has a list of its top neighbors, list of its left neighbors.  Recreate an excel file with merged cells that would match the connectivity of the given list of cells. the overall shape of the chart and each cell is rectangular and there are no voids inside the rectangle.  Overall plan: rebuild the lists of bottom and right neighbors for each cell. Then compute cell sizes.

I have a method that populates lists of right and bottom neighbors for each cell, but this method is slow O(n^2+). How can I make it faster?

I am writing a method that takes an arraylist, where each cell has a name and a listOfLeftNeighbors and an empty listOfRightNeighbors. Then it iterates over the lists and fills the listOfRightNeighbors using "if you have me in your listOfLeftNeighbors, then you are added to my listOfRightNeighbors. Then it returns the arraylist with listOfRightNeighbors populated for each cell.

```
private ArrayList<Cell> getRightNeighbors(ArrayList<Cell> set) {
    for (int i = 0; i < set.size(); i++) {           //for every cell in the list

        List<String> myLeftNeighbor = set.get(i).getLeft();  //get a list of left neighbors
        for (int j = 0; j < myLeftNeighbor.size(); j++) {    //For each left neighbor of a given cell
            String nameOfLeftNeighbor = myLeftNeighbor.get(j);
            for (int k = i + 1; k < set.size(); k++) {          //Check the list of cells and
                String kName = set.get(k).getName();
                if (0 == kName.compareTo(nameOfLeftNeighbor)) { //if name of k-th cell matches 
                    set.get(k).addRight(set.get(i).getName());  //To list of right neighbors add the name of i-th cell 
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return set;
}
```

This is at least O(n^2) complexity. Is there a way to make this method more efficient?

---

Briefly, initial data is provided by users in excel format. it is then processed by a topology processor. Each cell gets a name `getExcelName() + some_random_string`. The topology processor splits and merges cells multiple times. Sure, I can update coordinates of each cell (some 100K cells per spreadsheet) each time the topology processor splits A1, but this is not an efficient algorithm. Instead the topology processor manipulates the lists of left and top neighbors of the cells. Keeping interactions local. Once the topology manipulation is complete data should be converted to excel format.

---

I don't think the exact nature of the project is relevant. Imagine a set of connected pipes. Each pipe is connected to some upstream pipes `ArrayList<String> leftNeighbors` and a set of downstream pipes `ArrayList<String> rightNeighbors`. Question: given a set of pipes with a list of leftNeighbors (upstream), how can one efficiently populate the list of rightNeighbors (downstream)?

Comment: It looks like you're making some sort of tree and that you have membership testing. You should probably describe the data structure you're trying to build and why, as it is, it's just a couple of terribly named lists operated on by an inscrutable procedure.

Comment: I've added the explaination.

Comment: A look at the Cell class and perhaps an explanation as to why these cells are represented as they are would help us out a lot.  Specifically, why are what what are supposed to represent spreadsheet cells are in the form of a list of interconnected objects rather than elements within a two dimensional List or Array, which is a datastructure more closely resembling a spreadsheet (and is, most probably, how a spreadsheet is even implemented in most spreasheet programs).

Comment: I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a hash, assign each cell a number starting from 0. Make an array. Replace all cell names with these numbers. O(n) For each cell O(n) do this:
say you work with cell 8 and it has a neighbor 10. Then:   `listOfRightNeighblrs[10] = listOfRightNeighblrs[10] + ", 8";` O(1) (this is the key to  success).
Then translate back the cell names, for each cell O(n) populate its right neighbors from listOfRightNeighblrs O(1).
So far it should be close to O(n*averageNumberOfNeighbors).